# How can I get the expiration date of the facebook oauth token with the Accounts framework on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, token

With Facebook iOS SDK, the token for the user's Facebook account and its expiration date could be taken like:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] accessToken];
NSString *expires = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] expirationDate] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Now with the Accounts framework, I'm retrieving the user's Facebook token like this:

```
ACAccount *facebookAccount = //Get the account on the device
ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [facebookAccount credential];
NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
```

But I couldn't figure out how to retrieve the expiration date of this token. How do I do that? Or are there any other mechanisms that doesn't need the client side to deal with the expiration of the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Call **expiryDate** on the Facebook credential:

---

```
expiryDate = [fbCredential performSelector:@selector(expiryDate)];
```

Comment: This is not a good idea... this is a private property and is very prone to breaking.  If you want the expiration date, you should use the FB SDK.

Comment: It returns Jan 1, **4001**.